# Scraping table data transformed by dropdown selection (but same URL)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all the data in the first table (Regular Season) on this [page](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/B/BreeDr00/gamelog/). I could do it via the HTML tags, but the webpage has a handy drop-down feature for converting the table to CSV format which is exactly how I want the data:

drop-down 'Get table as CSV':

[image]

This results in the following CSV:

Resulting csv:

[image]

I have examined the HTML and when the dropdown is selected it modifies the HTML to include the CSV (i.e. it is not just 'hidden' and then exposed). I am assuming some javascript generates it. But the URL remains the same.

Is there a way (e.g. using BeautifulSoup) that I can execute this to generate the CSV?

Comment: Please post the text as text, not as images; see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @tripleee the images are example screenshots from the webpage, which I thought is appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the dataframe with beautifulsoup, then use pandas to write as csv file.

Or just use pandas to parse the table (then do a little clean up). Pandas uses beutifulsoup under the hood:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/B/BreeDr00/gamelog/'
df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[0]
df = df[df['Rk'] != 'Rk']
df = df[df['Rk'].notna()].reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('drew_brees.csv')
```